# How to change destination folder of compiled assets in PlayFramework 2.3.1?

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.3, sbt-web

Using PlayFramework 2.3.1, sbt-web, Scala 2.11.

How to change destination folder of compiled assets form "public" to "pub" for example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a pair of settings that you should modify for this. For example, to set it to "pub", you would do this:

```
import com.typesafe.sbt.web.Import.WebKeys.public // For Play 2.5.x
import com.typesafe.sbt.web.WebKeys.public // For Play 2.3.x

public in Assets := webTarget.value / "pub" / "main",

public in TestAssets := webTarget.value / "pub" / "test",
```

Comment: cannot resolve `public in Assets` and the `WebKeys` package

Comment: Yes, I'm sure.`WebKeys` can't be resolved.Console output `object WebKeys is not a member of package com.typesafe.sbt.web
import com.typesafe.sbt.web.WebKeys.public`.My project is based on [play starter project](https://github.com/playframework/play-scala) and it almost not change SBT config.

Comment: @LoranceChen - This question was referencing PlayFramework 2.3.1. The starter project is for PlayFramework 2.5.13. There is likely a difference in the web plugin between versions. Have a look around the the com.typesafe.sbt.web package to see where the "public" key went.

Comment: @LoranceChen: It is now [`import com.typesafe.sbt.web.Import.WebKeys.public`](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-web/blob/9b0ea5ea2a2ad0a76898bf7164e49ee733076e26/src/main/scala/com/typesafe/sbt/web/SbtWeb.scala)

Comment: @bluenote10 - Thanks, was that for Play 2.6? when was the change made?

Comment: @ReidSpencer I don't know exactly, just checked the current version which is 2.5 btw.